# New to Tango. Missing Library

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I am new to Tango and trying to get a hang of it. I am trying to execute tango examples from GitHub (https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java). However, I am facing a "INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_LIRARY" when I am using "com.projecttango.libtango_device2" library. Can you someone help me with these questions:

1. Do I need to use a tango enabled a device to run these sample tango applications or develop any tango enabled devices? I am currently using Nexus 5 and Google Pixel Tablet
2. If no required, any instructions on installing the library on the device I have?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do I need to use a tango enabled a device to run these sample tango applications or develop any tango enabled devices?

Yes. This is the problem you're seeing - you require a Tango device. Your devices are not Tango devices, hence `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_LIRARY`.